# How to, set-justification-full per line in emacs without messing up on return?

Tags: emacs

I have two problems in emacs.

First. 
How do I set-justification-full for the whole document?
I can do M-X set-justification-full for a region successfully, but I would like to make it work in the whole document.

Second.
How do I manage not to get lines jumping from one place to another when I have done set-justification-full, and press enter? That is, say I have the following paragraph:

```
%%if normalized beforehand then the rule would be,
%%\begin{gather}
%%(\hat{y}_{i}^{'} \times \hat{y}_{i+1}^{'}) \cdot \hat{z}_{mst} = 1, \quad then \ \Omega > 1\\
%%(\hat{y}_{i}^{'} \times \hat{y}_{i+1}^{'}) \cdot \hat{z}_{mst} =
%%-1,\quad then \ \Omega < -1
%%\end{gather}
```

When I do set-justification-full, it will convert six lines into three lines, that is, what I want to do is a per line justification. Is this possible in emacs?

Thank you all very much for your help.

Inhaki2006

---

Sorry about that. The example came without line breaks, what I meant was.

%%if normalized beforehand then the rule would be,
%%\begin{gather}
%%(\hat{y}*{i}^{'} \times \hat{y}*{i+1}^{'}) \cdot \hat{z}*{mst} = 1, \quad then \ \Omega > 1\

%%(\hat{y}*{i}^{'} \times \hat{y}*{i+1}^{'}) \cdot \hat{z}*{mst} = 
%%-1,\quad then \ \Omega
%%\end{gather}

Thanks again,

I.

Answer (score 0):

First, how about:

```
(defun set-justification-entire-buffer ()
  "do set-justification-full for the entire buffer"
  (interactive)
  (set-justification-full (point-min) (point-max)))
```